# What can I replace BasicNameValuePair with?

Tags: java, android

Could anyone please tell me or rewrite my code with the new method to replace basic namevalue pair as this is a deprecated method in API 22, Android studio application. `new BasicNameValuePair` is a deprecated method and I have tried to use value.put which has not worked for me. could you please advise.

```
  public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function to change password
     **/

    public JSONObject chgPass(String newpas, String email){
        List params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", chgpass_tag));

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newpas", newpas));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(chgpassURL, params);
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function to reset the password
     **/

    public JSONObject forPass(String forgotpassword){
        List params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", forpass_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("forgotpassword", forgotpassword));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(forpassURL, params);
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function to  Register
     **/
    public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
        return json;
    }
```

I have tried to use the below method however I am still getting an error. Could you please advise?

```
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("tag", login_tag);
    values.put("email", email);
    values.put("password", password);
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and add like this:

```
params.put("tag", forpass_tag);
params.put("forgotpassword", forgotpassword);

return params;
```

Comment: I have tried this however I get an error  JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);- Wrong second argument type.